# Python: Writing a code that recognizes an object and counts it

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

I am writing a python program that counts and recognizes the object in the image by using the colab, when I got an error in the following code,

```
drive_url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=jH_3&id=' + DATASET_DRIVEID
file_name = DATASET_DRIVEID + '.zip'

urllib.request.urlretrieve(drive_url, file_name)
print('Download completed!')

os.makedirs(DATASET_DIR, exist_ok=True)
with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip_ref:
  zip_ref.extractall(DATASET_DIR)
os.remove(file_name)
print('Extract completed!')
```

the file download was done successfully but I that the error showed in the extraction part as the following error:

```
Download completed!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BadZipFile                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6646b94bdb6f> in <module>()
      6 
      7 os.makedirs(DATASET_DIR, exist_ok=True)
----> 8 with zipfile.ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip_ref:
      9   zip_ref.extractall(DATASET_DIR)
     10 os.remove(file_name)

/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in __init__(self, file, mode, compression, allowZip64)
   1129         try:
   1130             if mode == 'r':
-> 1131                 self._RealGetContents()
   1132             elif mode in ('w', 'x'):
   1133                 # set the modified flag so central directory gets written

/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
   1196             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1197         if not endrec:
-> 1198             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   1199         if self.debug > 1:
   1200             print(endrec)

BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Your Python code looks correct except for the value of `drive_url`.

The error message indicates that the file named `file_name` is not a ZIP file. `urlretrieve` may have downloaded something else, such as an error page or a file of a different format. Maybe your `drive_url` is incorrect (i.e. it's not a download link use by your browser, but a web page link), or the uploader has deleted the file from Google Drive in the meantime, or you haven't specified the necessary cookies for the download.

Download `drive_url` using your web browser, and look at the downloaded file (e.g. use `file` command on Linux).

Comment: The url is working well, but I guess that the problem is when I manually try to  download the url it show me the window of that the web might has some viruses @pts

Comment: Instead of guessing, why don't you take a look at the downloaded file (as recommended in my answer)?

Comment: You need to use the same download link in your Python script as what your browser used. If you use Chrome, you can find the most recent download links on the `chrome://downloads/` page. You may also need to set up cookies: the Python script should use the same cookes as what your browser used -- you can ask a separate question on how to copy cookies from your browser to `urllib.request.urlretrieve`.